# Calculate directory path in Python module distribution

Tags: python, module, pkg-resources

I have a Python module distribution (it's an egg) that contains some additional files & directories that I would like to copy during my program's runtime.

```
├── mypkg
│   ├── extra_files
│   │      ├── layouts/
│   │      ├── scripts/
│   │      └── config.yaml
```

When `mypkg` is being used, I would like to copy all contents of `extra_files` directory to somewhere else on disk. Something like:

```
shutil.copytree('mypkg/extra_files', destination)
```

I've taken a look at `pkg_resources` however it seem like I can't calculate the path to a directory that way.

How can I calculate the path to files and directories in my distribution package? Do I need to first list all directories and then call `pkg_resources.resource_stream` on each file in each directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to actually do this with `__file__`, which returns the pathname from which the module was first loaded. I can get the full path to my static directory like this:

```
import os
directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/index.html')
```